# How to understand `constant(_), histogram` in `histogram.value` which is part of `d3.histogram` source code?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am learning d3-array by reading both doc and src. [`histogram.value`'s doc](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#histogram_value) is very detailed but I still find it difficult to grasp. [The source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/src/histogram.js) helps make more sense of doc, but I am still not very sure I understand the logic properly, majorly due to the use of `constant(_), histogram` the following line in particular:

```
(value = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(_), histogram)
```

Here is what I understand about `histogram.value(value)`:

```
histogram.value = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (value = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(_), histogram) : value;
  };
```

1. purpose of this code is to set `.value` using, `identity` or other functions;
2. if no arg is given, using `identity` function
3. if arg is given and arg is a function, then use this function
4. if arg is not a function, then set value to be  `constant(_)` in which `_` stands for the arg; but this part of code is  `constant(_), histogram`, I don't understand why there is a `histogram` here, nor I can figure out what exactly `constant(_)` wants to do.

by the way, is `constant(_), histogram` a use of [comma operator](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch09.html#comma_operator) ?  If it is, how could this help to understand the code above?

---

After reading @Mark and @zerkms 's answers, here is how I understand the following two lines of codes:

1. @Mark's code

   d3.histogram()
     .value(someFunc)
     .domain(someDomain)
     .thresholds(someThresholds);

is working fine for setting new custom functions for `.value`, `.domain`, `.thresholds`;

2. The following code causes error

   d3.histogram()
         .value()
         .domain()
         .thresholds();

because as @Mark made in the first point and clearly demonstrated in @zerkms' rewritten codes, that when there is no arg, `.value` only return `identity` function, not return `histogram`. Therefore, no more chaining is possible.

But we can access the default functions of `d3.histogram` by the following codes:

```
d3.histogram().value();
d3.histogram().domain();
d3.histogram().thresholds();
```

Is this correct?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code breaks down like this:

1. If no arg is given return the current value of value.
2. If arg is given and it is a function, set value to arg and return histogram function.
3. If arg is given and it's not a function, set value to a function that returns arg and return histogram function.

There's two confusing parts here:  what's the `constant(_)` and why are we returning `histogram`?

The `constant(_)` simply creates a function that when called will return arg.

The return `histogram` is returning the outer function to `value`. It is returned to allow for function chaining and is what allows you to do this:

```
d3.histogram()
  .value(someFunc)
  .domain(someDomain)
  .thresholds(someThresholds);
```

Since each return the parent function you can continue to build on the calls...

---

**Edits for comments:**

Yes, that would return the default values for those methods.  From the source code:

```
var value = identity,
  domain = extent,
  threshold = sturges;
```

You can check this yourself on the console:

```
> d3.histogram().value()
function f(t){return t}
> d3.histogram().domain()
function c(t,n){var e,r,i,o=-1,u=t.length;if(null==n){for(;++o<u;)if(null!=(r=t[o])&&r>=r){e=i=r;break}for(;++o<u;)null!=(r=t[o])&&(e>r&&(e=r),i<r&&(i=r))}else{for(;++o<u;)if(null!=(r=n(t[o],o,t))&&r>…
> d3.histogram().thresholds()
function d(t){return Math.ceil(Math.log(t.length)/Math.LN2)+1}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark for explaining the use of `histogram` inside the code.
 Based on @zerkms' rewritten code, it is clear to see that when arg is empty, `value` is returned (default value is `identity` function), and `histogram` is not returned.  
your code above

Comment: @Kenny, yes, your additional question is correct, see edits above.

Answer (score 2):

The whole

```
  histogram.value = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (value = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(_), histogram) : value;
  };
```

function could be rewritten as

```
histogram.value = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length) {
        value = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(_);
        return histogram;
    }

    return value;
};
```

So you are right that it's [a comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

And they do that just to save few statements and evaluate everything as a one extremely hard to read one.

Comment: Thank you @zerkms, I have edited a further question based on my understanding of your answer, could you have a look? (it is too long so I put it back in the question, instead of in the comment)